# AWS lambda does not write logs in the CloudWatch

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have made a simple **AWS lambda** and deployed it to with **AWSLambdaFullAccess** permissions. There was some logs after invocation. Next day I invoked the lambda again multiple times, all executions were successful but I didn't see any new logs into **CloudWatch**. 
I saw some logs only after redeploy the lambda

There is the code:

```
    public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        LambdaLogger.Log(input);
        return input.ToLower();
    }
```

Comment: Note that each unique invocation of your Lambda function does not necessarily equate to a new CloudWatch Log stream. The logs from invocation #2 may be appended to the log stream that was previously used for invocation #1. There is also a small delay between the Lambda function completing and all of its logs being available in CW Logs.

Comment: I know that, but this is not in my case. I didn't find any new logs in all streams previously used, and there is no new streams in CloudWatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda writes logs to a buffer which should be flushed after completing the lambda. But looks like for some reason lambda cannot flush it.
I have notified AWS team about it few weeks ago, but the issue still not fixed.

Comment: I think you're confusing what happens on your laptop with what happens in a globally distributed system of the scale and complexity of AWS.